# Cordova Android Material Design Date And Time Picker

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to implement a date and timepicker of material design which looks something like this:

[image]

The only timepicker I have successfully implemented in my Ionic Cordova android application is from this [link](https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-timepicker).

I'm wondering is there any already made plugins for cordova to use this kind of design or would I have to create a plugin to make it like this (if possible). I have done my search in Google and SO and did not find any related articles on this. Would appreciate if anyone has any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Try this.https://github.com/borax12/MaterialDateRangePicker

Comment: @Andy.Zhao Thanks for ur comment, but isn't that an android external library. I don't think i can install plugins like that with cordova.